# PostGIS - Why are my ST_Union results (stored in a new table) outputting as points and not polygons?

Tags: postgis, boundless-suite, dissolve, union

I've decided to move to PostGIS to merge polygons rather than spend hours doing in in QGIS. However, I'm hitting an issue where the results of an ST_Union query are being stored, or at least outputted as points and not merged polygons.

Here is my SQL query:

```
DROP TABLE opengeo.london_merged;
CREATE TABLE opengeo.london_merged (
  the_geom geometry(MultiPolygon),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_the_geom CHECK (geometrytype(the_geom) = 'MULTIPOLYGON'::text OR the_geom IS NULL)
);

INSERT INTO opengeo.london_merged 
SELECT ST_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom
FROM opengeo.tq_building
```

This is the output from the new opengeo.london_merged table that I'm getting:
[image]

However, if I just run a straight this same SQL on the orignal opengeo.tq_building table as an SQL view in GeoServer (so not creating a new table, just outputting the results):

```
SELECT ST_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom
FROM opengeo.tq_building
```

I get the following, correct output:
[image]

There's obviously something going on with how the new table is created or how the data is stored / retrieved from it, I just don't yet know enough about PostGIS to put my finger on it.

How can I store the ST_Union output in a new table so that the output is the expected polygons?

**Edit**

I ran the following SQL view on the opengeo.london_merged table in GeoServer and it gives me the correct output, suggesting that the data is stored correctly but it being outputted / given to me wrong when I view the table normally. Perhaps a type or SRID issue? I don't know.

```
SELECT the_geom FROM opengeo.london_merged
```

I'm still keen to solve this.

Comment: What's in the geometry_columns table for opengeo.london_merged?

Comment: Micha, opengeo.london_merged is a table. I can't find anything called geometry_columns anywhere. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Thanks Micha, it turns out Populate_Geometry_Columns() is what I was after so I've added an answer with the results.

Comment: The usual procedure for creating a spatial table is: create the table *without* a geom column, then run the AddGeometryColum() function to correctly set up the constraints and the entry in the geometry_columns table, and only at the end to insert data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a hint by Micha (below) I solved this by creating a new table with the results of the ST_Union query, however this time running the [Populate_Geometry_Columns()](http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/Populate_Geometry_Columns.html) method afterward to make sure the geometry types and SRID are correct.

This is the new, much cleaner SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE opengeo.london_merged_correct AS
SELECT
  ST_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom
FROM opengeo.tq_building;

-- Update the geometry_columns table
SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns();
```

Resulting in the correct output:
[image]

This process is [also documented here](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/geometry_returning.html#st-union).

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why do you need to update geometry columns here?